# Querying about field with JSON type value

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've the follow log:

> INFO  [http-nio-80-exec-30] class:ControllerV3,
>   M=method, UA=ua, URI=/v3/transactions,
>   QS=limit=21&offset=0&sort=-createDate, V=v3, P=3, RT=50,
>   ET=25, ELAPSE-TIME=50,
>
> REQ={"userId":98745569,"initialCreationDate":"2020-03-13T00:00:00","finalCreationDate":"2020-03-16T15:41:36","source":"SOURCE","statusIds":[2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,79],"accountingEntryType":"ENTRY_TYPE","considerPartialTransaction":true},
>
> GW=false

So I don't know how to get metrics and data about the `REQ` JSON field. I want know which values are passed on `statusIds`, `accountingEntryType`, `considerPartialTransaction` and the range of date of `initialCreationDate` and `finalCreationDate`. To get metric with normal field I use something like `| stats count by UA`. I'm newbie with Splunk and I don't know some functions to get the results.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to extract the `REQ` field and then use `spath` on it to extract the details from the JSON.

To extract the REQ field, you can use the following command. Note that this will not handle nested JSON, but if your events contain that, you can use a different regular expression.

```
| rex field=raw "REQ=(?<REQ>[^}]+})"
```

Once you have the REQ field, you can use `spath` to extract all the fields and values from the JSON, with the following command

```
| spath input=REQ
```

The following is an example showing that the extraction and spath work appropriately.

```
| makeresults | eval raw="
    INFO [http-nio-80-exec-30] class:ControllerV3, M=method, UA=ua, URI=/v3/transactions, QS=limit=21&offset=0&sort=-createDate, V=v3, P=3, RT=50, ET=25, ELAPSE-TIME=50,
    REQ={\"userId\":98745569,\"initialCreationDate\":\"2020-03-13T00:00:00\",\"finalCreationDate\":\"2020-03-16T15:41:36\",\"source\":\"SOURCE\",\"statusIds\":[2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,79],\"accountingEntryType\":\"ENTRY_TYPE\",\"considerPartialTransaction\":true},
    GW=false
    "
| rex field=raw "REQ=(?<REQ>[^}]+})"
| spath input=REQ
```

Comment: I don't understand how I can get the values and show it.

Comment: You just need to do `index=blah | rex field=raw "REQ=(?<REQ>[^}]+})" | spath input=REQ` to get the fields

Comment: so, to get initialCreationDate I can use REQ.initialCreationDate ?